# Google Compute VM hacked, now what?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've been running my Google Compute VM for literally 1 day, and I was hacked, by this IP: http://www.infobyip.com/ip-121.8.187.25.html 
I'm trying to understand what I can do next (user connected via ssh, root password was changed), to avoid these types of attacks (and to understand more than what /var/log/auth.log is telling me) ?

Comment: Any computer with sshd running on an externally accessible network interface will find itself under attack. By default GCE enables ssh access only via keys (as opposed to passwords). Did you enable password login? If so, how strong was your password?

Comment: I got hacked as well, and the worrying part is that I did not enable external ssh access via password. I understand that it's possible to find vectors of attack beyond the usual ssh/http, it's just I didn't think it would be so soon after creating the VM.

Comment: I've discovered that the entire IP range is under constant attack, my logs had login attempts within 5 minutes of instance creation

Answer (score 2):

I assume you deleted the instance already, right ? from Developers console.

As suggested, always use ssh rsa keys to connect to your instance, instead of passwords. Additionally, depending on where you want access from, you can only allow certain IPs through the firewall. Configuring the firewall along with iptables, gives you better security.

You may also want to take a look at [sshguard](http://felipeferreira.net/index.php/2011/07/how-to-setup-sshguard/). Sshguard will add iptables rules automatically when it detects a number of failed connection attempts.

Just to make sure, please change the default port 22 in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to something else.

Comment: I wasn't able to delete the VMs because they were might be protected from deleting by the hacker. But I successfully deleted the project itself. Is there any way that attacker can regain the access and can launch the VMs again? Also that happened because I mistakenly posted my private-key.json on git, because of that is my gcp still vulnerable?